# React element does not update even though the state is updated

Tags: html, reactjs, typescript

I'm fairly new to react and I'm trying to understand why this code does not function as expected. I have this drop down menu that when a link is clicked the menu would disappear. The `onClick` event is fired, but the UI is never updated.

Link with the onClick event

```js
     const link = items.url ? (
        items.url.includes("http") ? (
          <a href={items.url}>{linkContents}</a>
        ) : (
          <Link onClick={handleLinkClick} to={items.url}>{linkContents}</Link>
        )
      ) : (
        <div>{linkContents}</div>
      );

  return (
    <div className="relative bg-primary-white text-palette-base" ref={ref}>
      {items.submenu ? (
        <>
          <button
            title="dropDown"
            type="button"
            aria-expanded={dropdownOpen ? "true" : "false"}
            onClick={ handleLinkClick }
          >
            {depthLevel > 0 ? menuContent : chevronIcon}
          </button>
          <Dropdown
            submenus={items.submenu}
            dropdownState={dropdownOpen}
            depthLevel={depthLevel}
            customContent={items.customContent}
          />
        </>
      ) : (
        link
      )}
    </div>
  );
```

---

Here's where the state is read for the menu to either be `none` or `block` and I can see the new value being passed, but it is never reverted back to `none` when the link is clicked.

```js
      return (
        <div
          className={`p-2 absolute right-0 z-50 min-w-full list-none self-end rounded-lg border-solid border-2 origin-top animate-growDown shadow-md bg-palette-fill text-palette-base`}
          style={{ display: dropdownState ? "block" : "none" }}
        >
          {customContent || (
            <>
              {submenus.map(
                (submenu: MenuProps, index: React.Key | null | undefined) => (
                  <Menu items={submenu} key={index} depthLevel={depthLevel} />
                )
              )}
            </>
          )}
        </div>
      );
```

---

This is the `handleLinkClick` that updates the states.

```js
      const handleLinkClick = () => {
        console.log("Link clicked");
        setMenuState((prevState) => ({
          dropDownOpen: !prevState.dropDownOpen,
          chevronOpen: !prevState.chevronOpen,
        }));
      };
```

Comment: Where is `dropdownState` coming from?

Comment: It's in `Menu`

  const [menuState, setMenuState] = useState({
    dropDownOpen: false,
    chevronOpen: false,
  });. I updated my post with the return of `Dropdown`.

Comment: You have to use `menuState.dropDownOpen` and also watch the casing (dropDownOpen vs dropdownOpen)

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is how you're passing the state to handle the  style.

You're passing `dropdownState={dropdownOpen}`, but where dropdownOpen comes from? Maybe you meant pass `dropdownState={menuState.dropDownOpen}`?

Comment: Thanks, but no change for me unfortunately.

Comment: Try to add more information about the state you're using.